# Can't access Windows 10 after Ubuntu installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, mount

Today I've installed Ubuntu onto my PC. I have 2 physical hard drives in my computer. Ubuntu works fine but I can't access Windows anymore. It won't show up in the BIOS nor the Grub Bootloader. I've tried many solutions from other forum posts but nothing helped pretty much.

I tried the **boot-repair Tool**. This is the pastebin from it https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4MCsBsTQG3/

I also tried to manually add a entry in the Bootloader by editing my *40_custom.cfg* but it doesn't exist in /etc/default/grub.d ... I don't know why.

Then I downloaded the **Grub Customizer**, when I try to change the environment to my Windows Partition it gives me this error:

> Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
>   The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
>   could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.

I read about Windows hibernating when Fastboot is enabled but since I can't access Windows, I can't disable that option.

I also tried many things like `sudo update-grub` or `sudo os-prober` which also didn't help.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just discovered, that i installed Windows with Legacy Mode and not UEFI. Since i have all my personal data on another disk, i just reinstalled Windows on the same physical disk as Ubuntu and with UEFI. Now GRUB and Dualboot is working great !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered that I installed Windows with Legacy Mode and not UEFI. Since I have all my personal data on another disk, I just reinstalled Windows 10 on the same physical disk as Ubuntu and with UEFI. Now GRUB and Dualboot is working great!